# Passwords for registration and login of BCryptPasswordEncoder in Spring Security 6 do not match

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I haven't been able to solve the problem for a long time, I've read a lot of things, I still don't understand.

In general, I have a user registration form (Thymeleaf), data from it is transmitted to the controller, then the password is hashed and the data is sent to the database via JPA.

but

When I try to log in, my authorization does not work, allegedly the wrong password.

At the same time, if I hash the password on some website and manually enter it into the database, then I can log in later.

That is, if the hash is entered manually into the database, then I can log in. If the registration goes through my application, then I will not be able to log in.

The hash from the generator site is obtained with one version of the algorithm, and the hash that my application generates with a different version. Therefore, I do not understand how it is if I have only one PasswordEncoder bean for the entire application.

**Hash from the generator site**:

$2y$10$/mZ5HhyfMTml2xj0HYEX0uQfFgHDnsdJ3IhX0pReHUTRVSDuoqAPO

**Hash generated by my application**:

$2a$10$2U3MnmqMomhwWQpju1kuy.muBr7TPivlb.wn7XFilMAPJXlwaPx4.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/candidate/**", "/setup/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/chat/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","HEAD","USER")
            .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","HEAD")
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/cards", true)
            .permitAll()
        ).logout((logout) -> logout
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
        )
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

}
```

**Registration Form Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/setup")
class SetupController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String setupUser(User user) {
        try {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userService.save(user);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return "redirect:/setup?error=true";
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

I tried to use this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y);
}
```

and tried SHA-256, but it works the same. I can't login after registration.

Also, I tried to use this method:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return authProvider;
}
```

but the same.

Comment: *When I try to log in, my authorization does not work, allegedly the wrong password.* How do you know? Do you have any log? Your code seems okay. Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: @dur __How do you know?__ What? I have Thymeleaf error block on login page, like that `<div th:if="${param.error}">`. So, if there any error i see that wrong pass. In console I see that hibernate select all tables in DB. And nothing else. But if I manually enter password hash into the DB, I can log in.

Comment: @JimGarrison I can't see what happens in login controller, cuz its spring's logic (match passwords etc.). I have only GET Requests to link Thymeleaf templates.
And i know, that my app generate hash with `$2a`. But the most interesting things are:
1) Why I can log in with hash `$2y` generated online on some website and manually entered into the DB.
2) Then why my app generate `$2a` and I can't log in with it.
Remember, I have only one `@bean` for the whole app.

Comment: Spring Security supports both versions, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java AFAIR in my apps I use version `2a`.

Comment: @dur I match all hashes with my password, here: https://bcrypt-generator.com/ And what do you think? They match!

Comment: But why my app can't match pass with hash, that was generated in this app

Comment: @dur my pass is - 100

Comment: Without Spring Security `TRACE` logs, it is very hard to tell, what is going wrong. You need to add the logs to your question.

Comment: Are your sure the password `100` is in your request body? Use your dev tool in your bowser (F12) to check it.

Comment: @dur I saw my request and its like plain text. I send what I write. Talking about `Spring Security TRACE` - how can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved and it was damn stupid. In the `Spring Security TRACE` I saw that `user disabled`.